# UIImagePickerController, can I use it to take pictures and save them to a path in my app without having to save them in the photo app?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I want to allow users to take photos within the app I am developing, so I thought I can use UIImagePickerController, present the camera view, let the user simply snap the photo and then save it in Documents or whatever path makes sense to use.

What I am trying to understand is, when I take the photo can I tell the picker where to save the photo? I do not want the photo to show up in the standard photo app on my iPhone...

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

You will receive a dictionary called "info", one of the keys is UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage.  The object for that key is a UIImage.  You can save that to the documents directory.  You probably want to convert it to a JPEG or PNG first.  You could use this for PNG:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[imageData writeToFile:pngpath atomically:YES];
```

or this for JPG:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8f)];
[imageData writeToFile:jpgpath atomically:YES];
```

I assume you know how to construct jpgpath and pngpath.